# An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@UserId' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection

Tags: c#, sql, mysql-error-1064

I had a login page. once user successfuly logged in, they can view and manage their profile/information. This would be done by retrieving data from database and display on a formview.

However this following error appeared inside my userprofile.aspx.cs file:

```
Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@UserId' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.

Source Error: 

Line 44: 
Line 45:         // Assign the currently logged on user's UserId to the @UserId parameter
Line 46:         e.Command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = currentUserId;
Line 47: 
Line 48:     }
```

Userprofile.aspx:

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataKeyNames="UserId">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                UserId:
                <asp:Label ID="UserIdLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserId") %>' />
                <br />
                Password:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>' />
                <br />
                Email:
                <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>' />
                <br />
                HomeTown:
                <asp:TextBox ID="HomeTownTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("HomeTown") %>' />
                <br />
                HomepageUrl:
                <asp:TextBox ID="HomepageUrlTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("HomepageUrl") %>' />
                <br />
                Signature:
                <asp:TextBox ID="SignatureTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Signature") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
                    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <InsertItemTemplate>
                UserId:
                <asp:TextBox ID="UserIdTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("UserId") %>' />
                <br />
                Password:
                <asp:TextBox ID="PasswordTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>' />
                <br />
                Email:
                <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>' />
                <br />
                HomeTown:
                <asp:TextBox ID="HomeTownTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("HomeTown") %>' />
                <br />
                HomepageUrl:
                <asp:TextBox ID="HomepageUrlTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("HomepageUrl") %>' />
                <br />
                Signature:
                <asp:TextBox ID="SignatureTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("Signature") %>' />
                <br />
                <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                    CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
                &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
                    CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
            </InsertItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                UserId:
                <asp:Label ID="UserIdLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserId") %>' />
                <br />
                Password:
                <asp:Label ID="PasswordLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>' />
                <br />
                Email:
                <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>' />
                <br />
                HomeTown:
                <asp:Label ID="HomeTownLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("HomeTown") %>' />
                <br />
                HomepageUrl:
                <asp:Label ID="HomepageUrlLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# Bind("HomepageUrl") %>' />
                <br />
                Signature:
                <asp:Label ID="SignatureLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Signature") %>' />
                <br />

            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
    </p>
<p>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SecurityTutorialsConnectionString %>" 
            onselecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT UserProfiles.UserId, aspnet_Membership.Password, aspnet_Membership.Email, UserProfiles.HomeTown, UserProfiles.HomepageUrl, UserProfiles.Signature FROM aspnet_Membership INNER JOIN UserProfiles ON aspnet_Membership.UserId = UserProfiles.UserId">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </p>
<p>
        &nbsp;</p>

</asp:Content>
```

Userprofile.aspx.cs:

```
 protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get a reference to the currently logged on user
        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();

        // Determine the currently logged on user's UserId value
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

        // Assign the currently logged on user's UserId to the @UserId parameter
        e.Command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = currentUserId;

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
DbParameter param = e.Command.CreateParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@UserId";
param.Value = currentUserId;
e.Command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

I didn't test this though

Answer (score 7):

Create a new SqlParameter and add it to the collection.

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("@UserId", currentUserId);
e.Command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Comment: is there any namespace for sqlParameter? because the error-- The type or namespace name 'SqlParameter' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) occured

Comment: does that work for mysql? SqlParameter is meant for SqlServer (System.Data.SqlClient namespace)

Answer (score 0):

You must add the parameter with

```
e.Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
```

Once you have added it you could access it through the indexer as in your example.

---

#### UPDATE

If you are working with the `System.Data.Common` namespace, the `AddWithValue` method is not available. You will have to do something like

```
var param = e.Command.CreateParameter("@UserId", currentUserId);
e.Command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

This is a little bit more complicated but has the advantage that you do not have to implicitly create a parameter of a specific type like `SqlParamter` or `OleDbParameter`.

Comment: Hi, i had tried your code. but a compilation error appeared. Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection' does not contain a definition for 'AddWithValue' and no extension method 'AddWithValue' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Data.Common.DbParameterCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Apparantly the `AddWithValue` method only exists on specific types (SqlClient, ODBC, OleDb etc.); However you are working with `System.Data.Common` (which is perfectly OK).

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the parameter listed in your SqlDataSource, then simply point to it and change it's value ...

```
e.Command.Parameters["@UserId"].Value = currentUserId;
```

You do not need to create a parameter, unless you have not listed it back in your ASP page.