# Trouble passing parameter to SQL query OnSelecting event

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagridview, devexpress

I have an issue with a project I've inherited. It uses DevExpress and some of the grids have C# code that fills the datasource while others have ASP code that executes simple(ish) select and update queries.

One of the grids was showing too much info (the select query wasn't properly written) and there were too many options available to the user. This would be fixed with a simple `where` clause but I'm lost as to why my implementation isn't working. On the page there are three other grids that use the same technique but when I tried to copy it, it just doesn't work!

ASP:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
    ID="ds_Supplier" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Portal_ConnectionString %>" 
    OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [SupplierID], [SupplierName] FROM [tbl_Supplier] where BranchID = @BranchID" 
    OnSelecting="ds_Supplier_Selecting">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="0" Name="BranchID" Type="Int32" />
</SelectParameters>
```

C#:

```
protected void ds_Supplier_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Command.Parameters["@BranchID"].Value = GetBranchID();
    }
```

This throws the SQL error below:

```
An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@BranchID' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection
```

The confusing thing is that grids, directly above it and also below it follow the same logic and work with no hassles. I've seen other similar questions but those tend to lean towards populating the datasource via the C# code which doesn't really apply to this scenario. What have I missed?

Comment: You don't have any select parameters defined on your your datasource.

Comment: @SeanLange I have added the parameter code from the page - sorry I had posted another question previously and got crap because I'd apparently posted too much code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no feedback on why the method above wasn't working for me in this datagrid as opposed to the others where it did work, I have however found a solution:

```
protected void ds_Supplier_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Data.Common.DbParameter param = e.Command.CreateParameter();
        param.ParameterName = "@BranchID";
        param.Value = GetBranchID();
        e.Command.Parameters.Add(param);
    }
```

I used the answer from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275807/an-sqlparameter-with-parametername-userid-is-not-contained-by-this-sqlparamet) however I had to add `System.Data.Common.` before the `DbParameter` object reference as I was getting the error below:

```
The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

What was strange was that Visual Studio recognised the `CreateParameter()` function so I just tried adding `System.Data.Common.` to `DbParameter`and voila!

[image: The broken code]